# Fade In-Out for image in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, slider, slideshow

How can i implement FadeIn and then FadeOut image when i change image source like slide show. my images load from local and web and count of that is varaible.
Thankyou

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could write an extension method that fades out the image by animating its `Opacity` property to 0, then sets the `Source` property and finally animates the opacity back to 1.

```
public static void ChangeSource(
    this Image image, ImageSource source, TimeSpan fadeOutTime, TimeSpan fadeInTime)
{
    var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1d, fadeInTime);

    if (image.Source != null)
    {
        var fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0d, fadeOutTime);

        fadeOutAnimation.Completed += (o, e) =>
        {
            image.Source = source;
            image.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
        };

        image.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, fadeOutAnimation);
    }
    else
    {
        image.Opacity = 0d;
        image.Source = source;
        image.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF transition for this, please check at [Here](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I just want fadein-out effect and this transition has random effect and it's not good for me