# Animate ImageBrush Transition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-animation

I am building a WPF app to slideshow a sequence of images. For now, the slideshow images are hard-coded in the code behind class. The slideshow starts and stops by clicking the Click me button. I deliberately chose `ImageBrush` to be applied to `Background` property of `Grid` control, in place of the expected first choice of `Image` control, because I found that using `Image.Source` produces issues with the `DispatcherTimer` accuracy. Some images were displayed as expected, i.e., they followed `timer.Interval`, some were delayed, some were too short.

**I want to add fade in and out transition animation as the images cycle. How do I do that?**

Here is the current state of the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Temp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Temp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid x:Name="gridBackground">

    <Button Width="100" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="btnClickMe_Click">
        Click me
    </Button>
    
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Threading;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer timer;
    private Brush[] colors;
    private int counter;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        counter = 0;
        colors = new Brush[]
        {
            new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\boris\Desktop\Stikeri\02.png", UriKind.Absolute))) { Stretch = Stretch.Uniform },
            new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\boris\Desktop\Stikeri\03.png", UriKind.Absolute))) { Stretch = Stretch.Uniform },
            new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\boris\Desktop\Stikeri\04.png", UriKind.Absolute))) { Stretch = Stretch.Uniform },
            new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\boris\Desktop\Stikeri\05.png", UriKind.Absolute))) { Stretch = Stretch.Uniform },
            new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\boris\Desktop\Stikeri\06.png", UriKind.Absolute))) { Stretch = Stretch.Uniform },
        };

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter == colors.Length)
        {
            counter = 0;
        }
        gridBackground.Background = colors[counter];

        counter++;
    }

    private void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.IsEnabled = !timer.IsEnabled;
    }
}
```

If I am way off with my current approach, I'd be OK with ditching the `DispatcherTimer` in favor of some kind of animation defined in the code behind. I would, however, prefer to just slap some animation to the code I have already, if that is possible. Thank you!

Comment: As a note, your conclusion about Image "*producing issues with the DispatcherTimer accuracy*" is certainly wrong. If you had preloaded BitmapImages as you have now with the ImageBrushes, you would not observe any delayed loading (or whatever it actually was). Besides that, do you want to achieve some  kind of blending animation, where one image fades in while the other fades out? You would need two Images (or elements with ImageBrush backgrounds) that overlay each other.

Comment: For a fade out/fade in with a single element, something like this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19708196/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Thanks a lot. I've no idea how my images were not preloaded, but either way, this works and it also lets me mix up my brushes, i.e., not just use `ImageBrush`. Thank you for the link to the answer, it provided me with the direction I needed.