WPF Rectangle.Fill animate ImageSource change
I have a View, linked to a ViewModel.
On the View, there is a Rectangle, which displays an image.
The ImageSource is Data-Bound to a property in the ViewModel.
When the property in the ViewModel changes the image, I would like to fade-out the existing image, and fade-in the new image.
Here's some code:
        <Rectangle RadiusX="1" 
            RadiusY="1"
            Width="20"
            Height="20"  
            Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="0.1"                   
            Stretch="Uniform"                       
            >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>

Thank you, in advance for any suggestions.

It seems you haven't tried anything yet. Something similar to this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19708196/1136211

For a fade-over you may even need two Images or Rectangles.
